# How can I download a file in Python3 with urlopen() or add custom headers to urlretrieve()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers, user-agent, urlopen

tl;dr I want do download a file from a server who only allows certain `User-Agents`. I managed to get a `200 OK` from the site by using following code:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Interwebs Exploiter 4')]
opener.open(url)
```

Since the file can be a .pdf or .zip or another format, I want to download it without parsing or reading it. `Urlretrieve()` seems like a good idea but it uses the default header, which makes the server return a `403 Forbidden`.

How can I either download the file by using that custom built opener or simply add headers to `urlretrieve()`?

And [this example](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/python2.7/html/library/urllib.html#urllib._urlopener) in the Python Docs is complete gibberish to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `requests` for that:

```
import requests   

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Interwebs Exploiter 4'}

 r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

Unless it's absolutely essential for some reason to use `urllib`

Comment: Any way of doing it without installing additional dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Download an URL with `urllib.request`:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Interwebs Exploiter 4')]
with opener.open(url) as url_file:
    url_content = url_file.read()
```

Do note that `url_file.read()` will read the *entire* file into memory, which might not be what you want if it could be a very large file.